# IOS arc disabling for part of code

Tags: ios, objective-c, markerclusterer

I'm a newbie to IOS technology. I have been developing an app, in which I have to add around 10,000 mkannotations to my map. So I prefer to use clustering algorithm (probably using k_means). However, I found this beautiful external library at (https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/adclustermapview)

When I complied the example framework of this project and ran it on simulator everything works fine, however, when I add the required files to my project as they described, it raises a lots of errors regarding

```
retain
release etc.
```

So I understand there is some issue with the arc compatibility in the project

Here are my questions

1. These retain, release methods being used in some project, does
   that mean that they are developed with old versions of IOS?
2. If so, how do I resolve these error, other than manually removing them?
3. Is there a method in IOS, which allows me to compile a code
   partially using one compiler and the remaining using other?

Comment: As a side note, adding 10,000 annotations is likely to be really slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]Select desired files at Target/Build Phases/Compile Sources in Xcode

PRESS ENTER

Type -fno-objc-arc

Press Enter or Done

Answer (score 3):

In xcode Edit-Refactor-Convert to Objective-C ARC select your app then check button.Finally click save button.

Answer (score 1):

1. These retain, release methods being used in some project, does that
   mean that they are developed with old versions of IOS? **NO**
2. If so, how do I resolve these error, other than manually removing
   them?
3. Is there a method in IOS, which allows me to compile a code
   partially using one compiler and the remaining using other? **You can [disable ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project) for some files.**

Answer (score 1):

This problem might be coming because you must be using ARC in your project while this framework is not. To remove ARC for particular classes go to Targets, then build phases tab, under the compile sources group add '-fno-objc-arc' as the compiler flag. This will make sure that ARC is skipped while compiling this class..